# How can I reference the IntelliJ project path in my code?

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-idea-2016

I have a text file in my project and need to read its contents:

```
private final static String SOURCE_FILE = "C:/Project/resources/Source.txt";
```

Is it possible to use an IntelliJ variable?

```
private final static String SOURCE_FILE = "${ProjectDir}/resources/Source.txt";
```

I want to avoid hardcoding a path in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most circumstances, what you should do instead is put the file into a resources directory of your project/module (`src/main/resources` will work by default, you can create it if it doesn't exist) and access it using methods `getResource` or `getResourceAsStream` on `Class` and `ClassLoader`. See [Accessing Resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/lang/resources.html) guide from Oracle.

The major exception is if you need to pass this file to an external program.

Comment: I used `getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(FILE_NAME)`

Answer (score 1):

For example if you added a folder audio to your project structure then you could acces it like this:

```
new File(".\\Audio\\MyAudioFile.mp3")
```

Good luck, if you have any questions feel free to shoot 'em in comments :)

Comment: Because your java code looks at your source folder as if it's the only one, he lives in the source folder, it would behave differentley if you would for example say

       private final static String SOURCE_FILE = "C:/Project/resources/Source.txt";

Comment: That's not the real reason. Java code doesn't know about its source; this path is relative to the _working directory_, and when you run code from IDEA it will set the project directory as the working directory by default, which you can change.